# query returns correct result but collection returns wrong result

Tags: magento-1.9

I added this condition to my collection for adding the or condition:

```
$collection->addFieldToFilter(
array('city','mobile_badge'),
 array(array('eq' => $arealist),
'1'));
```

But it returns the wrong result.
This `$collection->getAllIds();` also returns the correct ids.
But when I execute

```
$collection->getSelect();
```

it's gives me correct values.

Answer (score 0):

Check your syntax for `addFieldToFilter` with multiple fields.

Your function should be like below:

```
$collection->addFieldToFilter(
    array('city', 'mobile_badge'),
    array(
        array('eq' => $arealist), 
        array('eq' => '1')
    )
)
```

Please refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3826474/magento-addfieldtofilter-two-fields-match-as-or-not-and) for better understanding.

Comment: Call to undefined method 
::getAllIdsSql()

Comment: Which collection are you using, custom module collection ?

Comment: yes this is custom module collection..

Comment: Updated my answer, please check.

Comment: no change still the same result..

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('{your_module_name}/{your_model_name}')->getCollection();
        $collection->addFieldToFilter(
            array('city','mobile_badge'),
            array(
                array('eq' => $arealist),
                array('eq' => 1)
            ));
        print_r($collection->getAllIds());
```